# How do I use chai and mocha with Grunt?

Tags: mocha.js

I am trying to use 'grunt-mocha-test' package but I can't find a way to hookup chai with this configuration. Do I need to manually configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply require chai in your spec files:

```
var chai = require('chai');
```